# toggleClass in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to toggleClass in reactjs. I know how to do this in Jquery but I need to do this in reactjs. The selector and classes I'm trying to apply the toggle as below. I attached my code at the bottom too.

$("#story-img:first").toggleClass("uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-2-3@m");

```
 const Layout = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul class="uk-grid-divider uk-child-width-1-1" uk-grid="true">
        <li>
          <div className="uk-position-relative" uk-grid="true">
            <div id="story-img" className="uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-2@m">
              <img src={props.img} />
            </div>
            <div id="story-text" className="uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-2@m">
              <p className="uk-text-meta uk-margin-small">{props.date}</p>
              <h3 className="uk-card-title uk-text-bold uk-margin-remove">{props.title}</h3>
              <p className="uk-text-small uk-margin-small">
                {props.label} &nbsp;|&nbsp; {props.description}
              </p>
              <p className="uk-text-small uk-text-uppercase" style={{ color: "#000!important;" }}>
                <a href={props.link}>{props.readMore}</a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <a href={props.link} className="uk-position-cover"></a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  )
};

export default Layout
```

I'm new to reactjs please guide me to solve this. Appreciate your time and effort for helping me.

Comment: Why do you think you need to toggleClass in React, where you can set classes dynamically in the JSX?

Comment: Because I only need to apply that class for the first list-item.

Comment: Again, though, why do you think you can't do that in React?

Answer (score 0):

You can use state for this:

```
const Layout = (props) => {
  const [className, setClassName] = useState('');

  const handler = () => {
    // This is the handler that's called for toggling class
    if (!className) {
      setClassName('some-class-to-add');
    } else {
      setClassName('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul class="uk-grid-divider uk-child-width-1-1" uk-grid="true">
        <li>
          <div className="uk-position-relative" uk-grid="true">
            <div id="story-img" className={`uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-2@m ${className}`}>
```